# How to add temporary column with data with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables : Users & User_friends, the users table holds data of the user like name, password, id, etc. the user_friends table holds both of the id's of user and another user from the same users table:

```
id | user_id | friend_id
 1 | 1 /Ben  |   2 / Dave
 2 | 1 /Ben  |   3 / Rob
```

So as you can see - Ben is friend with both Dave and Rob ( the names are just for visual representation).

I want to create a query that get all the users - but adds an indicator for 
who is friend with the logged user - which be passed as a paramater from PHP later on (bear with me here please).

The result i'm looking for is something like this:

```
id | user | isFriend
 2 | john |  true
 3 | bob  |  false
 4 | sam  |  false
```

Is it possiable with MYSQL or should i do it on the client side, with JavaScript?

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11238/4) are the tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. For each user in the `users` table, it gives you `id`, `name` and whether they are friends with (in this example) user 4 (this being the value you would pass as a parameter to the query):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, 
       EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM user_friends
              WHERE user_id = u.id AND friend_id = 4) AS isFriend
FROM users u
```

Results (for your sample data)

```
id  name    isFriend
1   roy     0
2   amit    1
3   oren    1
4   yaniv   0
5   shai    0
11  adi     0
12  eran    1
13  Nir     0
14  Ron     0
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11238/5)